# How to capture a field with the lookup?

Tags: apex, html, visualforce

I have the "quote" object and I want to print a field in the vfp (Tax Number) that is in the account object, and I have the "Account Name" field (API-AccountId) which is a lookup for the "Account" object...as do I print the value of "Tax Number" that is in the object "Account"?
It's probably simple but it's confusing me, I appreciate you giving me some light...

VFP:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" extensions="extWordDocQuoteCreator" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" cache="true">
<html>
<heade>
<apex:outputText value="{!quote.Account.Tax_Number__c}"/>
```

I have a select in the controller that gets the fields of the quote object...but I don't know if it's necessary for my question...
I am getting the following error: Invalid field Account for SObject Quote

### [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A merge field starts with `{!` and ends with `}`. You forgot the `!`, so it is parsed as just a normal string. Second, you need to start from the base record. If you're using a standard controller, it's the name of the object. In addition, standard fields don't use `__r` for a relationship, you just drop the `Id` from the field name. As such, the code you're looking for is likely:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Account.Tax_Number__c}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sfdcfox, I tried what you said and it returned the following error: Invalid field Account for SObject Quote :(

Comment: @GuedesSá Hmm, it works for me. I do recall something weird about the Account field, but it should work if everything is good. Check your page's API version, and make sure you're using `standardController="Quote"`.

Comment: I still don't quite understand why, but it worked when I used:```<apex:outputText value="{!quoteObj.Opportunity.Account.Tax_Number__c}"/>```
I imagine it must be something with the structure

Comment: @GuedesSá so, you're using a custom query in your Apex, rather than normal SOQL Visualforce binding, is all. Nothing wrong with that.